# Android: Converting SVG shape animation to native Android shape animation

Tags: android, animation, svg, drawable, objectanimator

Problem: I have an simple SVG animation that I really dig. I'd like to use it in my Android app. We all know that Android and SVG doesn't play well together without third-party libraries. And even then, the libraries don't support animation. One way around this is to use a WebView. WebView's can do SVG, and do it pretty well. But it feels a bit hacky to do an animation that way.

All this presupposes that I want to use SVG. I actually don't. Ideally I'd like to use Android's native XML drawable/animation to define this thing. I'm sure this is a pretty simple thing to do in code, but ideally it can be done without. And it doesn't have to be a perfect 1:1 conversion.

Let's start with the SVG:

```
<!-- By Sam Herbert (@sherb), for everyone. More @ http://goo.gl/7AJzbL -->
<svg width="44" height="44" viewBox="0 0 44 44" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke="#fff">
<g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-width="2">
    <circle cx="22" cy="22" r="1">
        <animate attributeName="r"
            begin="0s" dur="1.8s"
            values="1; 20"
            calcMode="spline"
            keyTimes="0; 1"
            keySplines="0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1"
            repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <animate attributeName="stroke-opacity"
            begin="0s" dur="1.8s"
            values="1; 0"
            calcMode="spline"
            keyTimes="0; 1"
            keySplines="0.3, 0.61, 0.355, 1"
            repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </circle>
    <circle cx="22" cy="22" r="1">
        <animate attributeName="r"
            begin="-0.9s" dur="1.8s"
            values="1; 20"
            calcMode="spline"
            keyTimes="0; 1"
            keySplines="0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1"
            repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <animate attributeName="stroke-opacity"
            begin="-0.9s" dur="1.8s"
            values="1; 0"
            calcMode="spline"
            keyTimes="0; 1"
            keySplines="0.3, 0.61, 0.355, 1"
            repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </circle>
</g>
```

As I understand it, all this basically does is define two circles. Each circle animation lasts 1.8 seconds, with the second one beginning 900 milliseconds before the first one finishes its animation. Both circles move in a non-linear fashion -- what I'd call an accelerate/decelerate interpolator. I'm probably wrong about that last part.

Anyway, so the XML to define a shape and animate it is pretty simple:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape
        android:shape="oval">

        <solid
            android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@android:color/white" />

    </shape>
</item>
```

And either this:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:duration="1800"
 android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
 android:shareInterpolator="true">

<set>
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1"
        android:toAlpha="0"

        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="restart"/>

    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:toXScale="4"
        android:toYScale="4"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"

        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="restart"/>

</set>
```

Or this:

```
<set>

    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="scaleX"
        android:duration="1800"
        android:repeatCount="1000"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:valueFrom="1"
        android:valueTo="4"/>

    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="scaleY"
        android:duration="1800"
        android:repeatCount="1000"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:valueFrom="1"
        android:valueTo="4"/>
</set>

<objectAnimator
    android:propertyName="alpha"
    android:duration="1800"
    android:repeatCount="1000"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:valueFrom="1f"
    android:valueTo="0f" />
```

Still with me? What I can't figure out, and why I'm here, is to kick off the a second animation. I tried layering two ImageViews on top of each other, and animating them 900ms apart. That got me almost the way there. But not quite.

So my questions are these:

- Can we kick off two animations in a not quite sequential fashion? Meaning, can we kick off an animation -900ms before the first one ends?
- Can we grow the circle without scaling it up? The SVG doesn't change the size of the stroked image. Scaling a drawable does. This is not critical, but I thought I'd ask.
- Am I missing the boat here? Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks for your time.